# Convert 32float SAR image to a grey-scale uint8

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, satellite-image

I'm working with SAR images from Sentinel-1. I use [SNAP library](http://step.esa.int/main/community/developers/) to get images in geotiff format. These geotiff have two layers: one for Intensity_VH and the other for Intensity_VV.

The problem is that the data type of the geotiff is float of 32 bits, and I need it as uint8.

Currently, I'm using [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and opencv2 in python to downcast the numpy matrix:

```
black_white_band = np.add(band1, band2) / 2
image = np.dstack((black_white_band, black_white_band, black_white_band))    
final_image = cv2.normalize(image, None, 0, 255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
```

But the loss of information is too high:

Image with 32 bits float:

[image: Image with 32 bits float]

Image with 8 bits int:

[image: Image with 8 bits int]

How can I convert two layers of 32 bits float in a grey-scale image of 8 bits? When I use Photoshop to simply open the image and export it as jpg it throw the next result, which is pretty good:

[image: Image with 8 bits int from photoshop]

### **- First update**

[This is the original image file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XV3mSDYUaNcRWtgPyI5K-_Z-HhmcaGBw/view?usp=sharing).

### **- Second update**

I also tried doing an equalization of the histogram. The results are good but the whites are exaggerated:
[image]

Comment: Use `skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(image, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: won't work. obviously there are outliers in the image and this needs something smarter than a linear mapping between min and max values. present a histogram of the input data (from photoshop or wherever). or present (upload) the original data or original as TIFF. then we can talk.

Comment: NORM_MINMAX is not the best choice. Try with NORM_L1 or NORM_L2. Unfortunately, the documentation is virtually mute about these options.

Comment: Thank you all. I tried with skimage but got the same results. With NORM_L1 or NORM_L2 the results are worse. I uploaded the image on google drive and put the link in the question.

Comment: I updated the question with a new image using histogram equalization. I got better results but are not the same as in photoshop case.